# How do I fetch mulitiple rows using fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) with pdo?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch, loops

testQuery() is the method I use to get all rows from table CATEGORIES

```
public function __construct()
 {
 self::$tdb = Database::getConnection();
 }



 #mock query to pull results from db
 public function testQuery()
  {
       $queryAA = "SELECT cat_name, cat_description, cat_id FROM CATEGORIES";
       $stmtAA = self::$tdb->prepare($queryAA);


       if ($stmtAA->execute() == true)
        {
             print("Execution was successful");
             return $stmtAA->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
        }
       else
        {
            print("Warning statment did not successfully execute");
        }
     }
```

I normally use fetchAll() but I was told to use fetch as it doesn't take up as much memory.
But I am having trouble retrieving more than one row using fetch() and the code below.

```
$test = new test();
$results = $test->testQuery();


foreach ($results as $row)
 {
 print_r($row);
 }
```

It only fetches 1 row. So how do I retrieve and print multiple rows? Using iteration was mentioned before but I'm not sure to implement it. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return the statement object.
Or if you want to encapsulate it (so that it can only be used to fetch the data) use [the SPL's IteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php)

```
return new IteratorIterator($stmtAA);
```

then you can use

```
foreach( testQuery() as $row) { ... }
```

in your script.

Comment: Perfect^ that's this iterator object is new to me I'll have to look into but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Fetch does indeed pull the data from the database one at a time, but you need to iterate through the rows until you have all the data.

You might want to pop this into a loop to get all the data:

```
$stmtAA->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Something like this should do the trick:

```
while($row=$this->prepared->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $this->ID=$row['id'];
    $something=$row['something'];
}
```

Depending on if you are populating variables or have the code within an object.

Comment: Is it possible to I put a condition for this `while()` ? because I want just 10 first rows *(suppose the result is 11 rows)*

Comment: @Sajad Of course. You can have multiple conditions inside the `while` clause - though if you are using MySQL, I would suggest using a `limit 0,10` clause on the end of your query to ONLY return the first ten rows (ordered by your `order by` clause) which does the same thing only better.